# I am not able to open google chrome in selenium 2.53

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a simple script of opening Google Chrome browser . I am using selenium 2.53 with Chromedriver version 2.25 and below is my code

```
package openingGoogle;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

on **new ChromeDriver();** it is getting red underlined and on placing mouse over it , says

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

What changes I need to do in my code ?

Comment: also **import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;** is getting red underlined as ChromeDriver is not imported .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is in your Class name, as you have created your class with same name which is existing class in Selenium Framework.

Suggestion - Rename your class to some other and then try

Comment: next time definitely you won't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Change java class name to something else. Don't have same name as ChromeDriver.

Like..

```
public class ChromeDriverTest
{
}
```

and change file name too.